# Bash-completion breaks hosts tab completion

Tags: terminal, bash

Prior to installing [Bash Completion](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion), hitting the "tab" key after an "@" character would autocomplete hostnames listed in /etc/hosts.

For example, if I started typing:

```
drush @lo [tab]
```

It would autocomplete to

```
drush @localhost
```

Since there is an entry in /etc/hosts for

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

After installing [Bash Completion](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion), that functionality no longer worked. Is there anything I can do to restore that functionality while also keeping [Bash Completion](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion) installed?